# How many students correctly answered all three tasks?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> How many students had all right answers when $20$ had right first task, $16$ had right second task, $15$ had right third task, $10$ students had right both first and second task, $8$ had right first and third task, and $9$ had right second and third task? Every student had at least one task right. I don't know if I have to apply inclusion-exclusion principle or if it's possible to calculate it without it. I forgot to mention that there are $31$ students.

I tried to apply inclusion-exclusion principle and I ended up with result $7$. Please correct me if I am wrong. I wrote out equation for union of $3$ sets, then I calculated what I could and ended up with $|A \cap B \cap C|+24 = 31$, so $|A \cap B \cap C| = 7$.

Comment: How many students are there in all?  With the way it is written you have two missing pieces of information and one equation.  That is not enough.

Comment: With what you have written, we know $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$ and so $|A\cup B\cup C|=24+|A\cap B\cap C|$.  It could be there are $24$ students in total and none got all three right.  It could be there are $32$ students in total and $8$ got all three right.  It could be any integer between.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes i forgot to mention that there are 31 students in total

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for three sets states that
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$
If we define $A$ as the set of students who correctly answered the first task, $B$ as the set of students who correctly answered the second task, and $C$ as the set of students who correctly answered the third task, then we were given
\begin{align*}
|A \cup B \cup C| & = 31\\
|A| & = 20\\
|B| & = 16\\
|C| & = 15\\
|A \cap B| & = 10\\
|A \cap C| & = 8\\
|B \cap C| & = 9
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
|A \cap B \cap C| & = |A \cup B \cup C| - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|\\
& = 31 - 20 - 16 - 15 + 10 + 8 + 9\\
& = 7
\end{align*}
as you found.